# Code pasted, but it executed reversed order of row on Android SSH client

Tags: android

When use an terminal application on android such as Terminus and i create a code snippet or just paste the copied code Function to the powershell terminal. It execute reversed order from Final line to First. Althought originaly all row of code order is ascending not descending. How can i fix that to run code in normal order without delete all line break?

Sample code in original format:

```
Function Get-DiskSize {$Disks = @()
 $DiskObjects = Get-WmiObject -namespace "root/cimv2" -query "SELECT Name, Capacity, FreeSpace FROM Win32_Volume"
 $DiskObjects | % {
 $Disk = New-Object PSObject -Property @{
 Name           = $_.Name
 Capacity       = [math]::Round($_.Capacity / 1073741824, 2)
 FreeSpace      = [math]::Round($_.FreeSpace / 1073741824, 2)
 FreePercentage = [math]::Round($_.FreeSpace / $_.Capacity * 100, 1)
 }
 $Disks += $Disk
 }
 Write-Output $Disks | Sort-Object Name
}
```

Code in pasted format:
[image: Code in pasted format]

Comment: is this code written in notepad and you are copying from notepad and then paste into cmd , is that correct understanding ?

Comment: This code copied from https://www.easy365manager.com/powershell-get-disk-free-space/ , then copied into Notepad in Android, then copied from notepad to cmd

Comment: is it compulsory to run it like this ? I think we can run the code from text file in which you have copied the code !

Comment: On android? How to run it from text file?

Comment: isn't this console which you have added image is cmd ?

Comment: this is the console where I pasted the script from txt/forum